# Enabling Bitlocker in Native VHD Boot

Tags: security, windows-8, bitlocker

I have a laptop with a single hard drive, using the GUID Partition Table (GPT) disk layout, with the following partitions:

- 120MB EFI System Partition
- 300MB Microsoft Reserved Partition (MSR)
- Remainder - GPT primary partition

I have a Windows 8 Professional VHD configured as a native-boot VHD on the GPT primary partition. Can I use Bitlocker to encrypt my main partition, or to encrypt the VHD volume?

Answer (score 2):

> ...and BitLocker cannot be used on volumes that are contained inside a
>   VHD.

I've read that TechNet article, but I've found that the VHD actually *can* contain encrypted volumes. I tried it and it worked fine. Of course, you have to have an unencrypted partition on a hard drive to boot onto first (where Bootmgr resides).

However, the VHD can't be on an encrypted host volume, as the article states, and even suspending BitLocker doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single physical disk in your system, and you are native VHD booting to a VHD file on that physical disk, then you cannot use Bitlocker on the physical disk partition where the VHD is booting from, and you cannot use Bitlocker on the VHD itself either. You may be able to use Bitlocker on additional partitions that are not being booted to.

**Source**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825689.aspx#BKMK_limitations

> Windows® BitLocker® Drive Encryption cannot be used to encrypt the host volume that contains VHD files that are used for native VHD boot, and BitLocker cannot be used on volumes that are contained inside a VHD.